# How to state multiple words for a single result in IndexOf

Tags: javascript

Hello So i have A HTML page that i'm trying to pull multiple things from one index of.... because my coding is starting to get extremely bulky.

```
                    if(str.indexOf("Ore") >-1){
                        var Final = Ore;
                    }
```

This is what i have...but say i want to add the word "Ingot" so that it would search for Either Ore or Ingot.  And if it found it would set it Final to Ore.

I have tried writing all of my lists out but after several hundred lines just to change something...yea that's a pain.  Please help.

Comment: Have you tried `if(str.match(/Ore|Ingot/)){`?

Comment: I don't see why this wouldn't do:
`if(str.indexOf("Ore") >-1 || str.indexOf("Ingot") ){
                        var Final = Ore;
                    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
if(str.indexOf("Ore") >-1||str.indexOf("Ingot") >-1){
                        var Final = "Ore";
                    }
```

Check Both of the strings . This code will check both of those strings and if that page contains any of those two strings ,  The value of Final variable will be `"Ore"` .

Comment: Thank you, I'll also assume that this works for even more which is perfect so thank you once again

Answer (score 0):

You need to write regular expressions for single statement search. Try this:

```
if(str.match(/Ore|Ingot/))
```